# String to dictionary conversion in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

Result string contain input string : `1 2 3 a b c`

Expected op:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

what I tried :

```
resultKV=result.Split('\t');
foreach (string KV in resultKV)
{
    Console.WriteLine(KV);                    
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Build a Dictionary with index/char key value from the input string? Under what condition?

Comment: You're going to need to define your question better.  It's hard to be clear of the exact constraints on your input, and how you want your output. There is no dictionary in your sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var parts  = "1 2 3 a b c".Split();
var dict = parts.Select((s, inx) => new { s = s, inx = inx })
                .GroupBy(x => x.inx % (parts.Length / 2))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.First().s, x => x.Last().s);
```

Using side-effects, it can be done shorter

```
var parts  = "1 2 3 a b c".Split();
int inx = 0;

var dict = parts.GroupBy(x => inx++ % (parts.Length / 2))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.First(), x => x.Last());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "1 2 3 a b c";
var parts = input.Split(' ');
if (parts.Length % 2 == 0)
{
    var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var halfLength = parts.Length / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < halfLength; i++)
    {
        d[parts[i]] = parts[halfLength + i];
    }

    // at this stage the dictionary will contain the desired result
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Must have a pair number to build the dictionary");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand the problem, I'd solve it this way:
**1.** split the input string in half, such that you have part1 and part2
**2.** iterate over one of the strings and print out characters one by one

I dont know any c# but that should be pretty easy to implement
**Edit**
if you want to apply the solution to other strings, you might want to check on things like if both parts have the same length etc.

Answer (score 0):

does the split result in more than one item? Or in other words: is it the right escape sequence ?
if so, maybe u can do anything like:

`int l = resultKV.lenght/2;`

`if(l % 2 == 0)`

`for(int i = 0; i < l; i++){`

`Console.WriteLine(resultKV[i]); Console.WriteLine(resultKV[i+l]);`

`}`
(not tested)